# Get errors from Tomcat log in real time

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to make a script to get certain errors from Tomcat log or maybe get them **before** Tomcat prints the erros to catalina.out. After getting error X, Y or Z, I want it to run a certain command, like *sendmail*.
What methods I could use to achieve this?

I know I can *tail -f catalina.out* to see it in real time, but I'm not sure if I can make a script to monitor this.

I'm using CentOS 7.5 along with Tomcat 7.2.

Comment: Searching for something like `linux log watcher` will turn up several  solutions in the first few links. Have you tried any of these yet?

Comment: you could make a file watcher in Perl with some good modules reading logs in real time and triggering actions

Comment: I found a program called sec. I'm testing it now. Thanks!